# Detecting consecutive patterns in an Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays

Before you accuse this thread for being a duplicate, just realize that (from what I've seen) are finding patterns within String arrays, which seem to have a lot of extra code that is unneeded for my purposes.

**How can I find patterns within an int array?**
If I have an array that has >500 integers, I need to test for patterns of ~4 different values consecutively. What's a good/fast way to do this?

Here's an example:

```
17,39,78,324,43,33,234,99,34,555,39,78,324,43,45,92
```

Hard to tell, but the numbers `39,78,324,43` are repeated twice, in that order. This is what the algorithm needs to be able to detect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "~4 different values"? Are you looking for patterns repeated just twice? Or possibly more? Your question is rather unclear.

Comment: This seems to be similar with the LRS (longest repeated substring) or similar problems

Comment: @Djizeus the 4 values like `39,78,324,43` just repeated at least once.

Comment: Try to implement *string matcher algorithmn*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understood your question, the simplest solution would be (Though you can make it more efficient)

```
public class FindConsecutiveNumber{

public static void main(String[] args){
    int i,j;
    int[] c = {17,39,78,324,43,33,234,99,34,555,39,78,324,43,45,92};
    for( i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        for( j = i+1; j < c.length-i; j++)
        {
           if(c[j] == c[i]){

                  if(c[j+1] == c[i+1] && c[j+2] == c[i+2] && c[j+3] == c[i+3])
                   {
                       System.out.println(c[i] + "," +c[i+1] + ","+c[i+2] + ","+ c[i+3] );
                       break;
                   }

           } 
        }


    }
}

}
```

my ourput is like this`39,78,324,43`

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 outcomes to what you desire.

If you just have to print how many times each number is repeated, you can create 2 for loops which are nested and iterate through the whole array in the inner loop to find matching integer to the outer loop and once done, print the number of times the integer was repeated.

If you have to store how many times an integer is repeated, you can follow the same process, but this time you need to store the number and how many times it is repeating in an array and then print it.

Also remember that in both cases you will need to make an array that stores numbers that have been counted so that you don't count them again.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for. As Konstantinos said, I'm looking for the longest repeated consecutive set of integers, not just one.